# QImage: URL instead of file path?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qwidget

[image]

This code assigns a raster pixmap to a label.
Instead of generating one I could simply read a local file:

```
img = QtGui.QImage('/Users/user/Desktop/photo.jpg')
```

I wonder if there is a way to specify the URL link instead of file path? Then `QLabel` would get its pixmap straight from a web?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not QtGui.QApplication.instance():
        app=QtGui.QApplication([])

    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

    img = QtGui.QImage(32, 32, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    img.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)
    lbl = QtGui.QLabel()
    lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    window.layout().addWidget(lbl)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I hope you don't want to set straight away url to your widget(qlabel) which cannot be done.So the alternate is to download an image form url and set it to a widget(QLabel).In this case  you need to use QNetworkManager to download the image from web and then set the image to widget.Please read docs to use QNetworkManager(for downloading content using url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way of getting a QImage or QPixMap to load data straight from a URL. But you can bypass that by first extracting the data from the URL, and then loading it to a QPixMap.

**Get data from the URL:**

```
import urllib2 
url_data = urllib2.urlopen(path).read()
```

**Now load it to your QPixMap:**

```
pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(url_data)
lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

It is worth saying you should try and catch exceptions like `urllib2.URLError`
or `InvalidURL`, handle cases where the URL is secured (https) etc.

Comment: on python3.x 'import urllib.request' and use 'urllib.request.urlopen().read()'

Comment: Note this blocks the GUI while the download is running, which might be a problem depending on your connection. It would be better to use a [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and do the download async.

Answer (score 0):

'''

import requests

'''
imageurl = "your url here"
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

try:
with requests.get(image_url, headers=headers, stream=True) as response:
response.raise_for_status()

```
    # Read the content in chunks to handle large files
    url_data = b""
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
        url_data += chunk
```

'''

```
# Continue with your image processing code
image = QImage()
image.loadFromData(url_data)
image_label = QLabel()
image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(image))
# image_label.setFixedSize()  # Adjust the size as needed
layout.addWidget(image_label)
```

'''
except requests.HTTPError as e:
print(f"Failed to retrieve image. HTTP Error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
'''